# Eclipses code analysis doesn't work with git project

Tags: eclipse, git, code-analysis, pep8

I have imported a git project into Eclipse 
and I want to enable PyDev\Code Analysis\Pep8
but it doesn't seem to work...
I suppose it is because its a git project and not a project in the eclipse's workspace..
How can I make Pep8 code analysis work?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, I don't get anything. I suppose if it was working, warnings and errors would appear, but instead nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on the folder of cloned folder in Eclipse 
PyDev -> Set as source Folder
Is becomes real eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that PyDev will only do code-analysis on files which are under source folders (i.e.: in the project PYTHONPATH).

Please, read the Getting Started manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html which has a step-by-step on how to properly configure PyDev so that it works properly for you.